# Keras Conv2D kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras-layer

In the notebook [convolution-and-relu](https://www.kaggle.com/ryanholbrook/convolution-and-relu) it is mentioned that convolution is done in keras with

```
    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')
```

Later, the tensor flow equivalent function is given as

```
image_filter = tf.nn.conv2d(
    input=image,
    filters=kernel,
    # we'll talk about these two in lesson 4!
    strides=1,
    padding='SAME',
)
```

I understand the tensorflow conv2d function. But, I do not understand how the keras Conv2D is equivalent.

Question: For keras.layers.Conv2D where is `kernel` given?, how are `filters` calculated?

Comment: Filters are not calculated but learned, this happens internally in the layer. The weights are random initialized at the start of training.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, in other words, the above two are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In `tf.nn.conv2d`, you need to set `filters` to a multidimensional array (tensor) that you've created in advance. If you want to perform convolution with 64 kernels of size 3x3, the input tensor must have those dimensions.

In `layers.Conv2D`, Keras manages the multidimensional array for you, but you configure the array's dimensions. That is, the number of kernels in the array will be set equal to the `filters` argument. The dimensions of each kernel will be set to `kernel_size` by `kernel_size`.